# jquery in separate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to use Jquery in a separate .js file which is included in my main .html.

Main HTML:

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

myscript.js

```
function includeJS(jsPath){
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
js.setAttribute("src", jsPath);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
}
includeJS("Libraries/jquery.min.js");
```

this is the error I got from the browser
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (inside the jquery.min.js file)

And This same jquery file works otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly getting a 404 error or something when that script is loading. It is trying to parse the html it is getting back as javascript. That is what causes the syntax error.